# Otherwise in Oracle BI Publisher not Working

Tags: xml, oracle, report, rtf, bi-publisher

I have the following XML structure from My Data Set:

```
<DATA_DS>
<G_1>
<INVOICE_NUMBER>20005</INVOICE_NUMBER>
<BATCH_SOURCE_NAME>MIGRATION</BATCH_SOURCE_NAME>
<CT_REFERENCE/>
</G_1>
<G_1>
<INVOICE_NUMBER>454162</INVOICE_NUMBER>
<BATCH_SOURCE_NAME>FM Source Number</BATCH_SOURCE_NAME>
<CT_REFERENCE>454162</CT_REFERENCE>
</G_1>
<G_1>
<INVOICE_NUMBER>455920</INVOICE_NUMBER>
<BATCH_SOURCE_NAME>FM Source Number</BATCH_SOURCE_NAME>
<CT_REFERENCE>455920</CT_REFERENCE>
</G_1>
</DATA_DS>
```

I have put the following logic in my RTF Template inside a FOR-EACH in a Table:

```
<?choose:?>
<?when://BATCH_SOURCE_NAME='FreightMaster'?><?CT_REFERENCE?><?end when?>
<?when://BATCH_SOURCE_NAME='FreightMaster-deactivated'?><?CT_REFERENCE?><?end when?>
<?when://BATCH_SOURCE_NAME='FM Source Number'?><?CT_REFERENCE?><?end when?>
<?otherwise:?><?INVOICE_NUMBER?><?end otherwise?>
<?end choose?>
```

However, my data isn't coming up correctly. It's showing as:

```
Invoice Number
-----------------
<null>
454162
455920
```

It was supposed to be like below:

```
Invoice Number
-----------------
20005
454162
455920
```

When I try to define `MIGRATION` as an option, it works:

```
<?choose:?>
<?when://BATCH_SOURCE_NAME='MIGRATION'?><?INVOICE_NUMBER?><?end when?>
<?when://BATCH_SOURCE_NAME='FreightMaster'?><?CT_REFERENCE?><?end when?>
<?when://BATCH_SOURCE_NAME='FreightMaster-deactivated'?><?CT_REFERENCE?><?end when?>
<?when://BATCH_SOURCE_NAME='FM Source Number'?><?CT_REFERENCE?><?end when?>
<?otherwise:?><?INVOICE_NUMBER?><?end otherwise?>
<?end choose?>
```

The actual output matches the expected output:

```
Invoice Number
-----------------
20005
454162
455920
```

I know i can just specify the Source Names in the `WHEN` clause, but there are over 20 Source Names and I'd like to simplify the code.

Any idea why it isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?choose:?>
   <?when:BATCH_SOURCE_NAME='FreightMaster'?><?CT_REFERENCE?><?end when?>
   <?when:BATCH_SOURCE_NAME='FreightMaster-deactivated'?><?CT_REFERENCE?><?end when?>
   <?when:BATCH_SOURCE_NAME='FM Source Number'?><?CT_REFERENCE?><?end when?>
   <?otherwise:?><?INVOICE_NUMBER?><?end otherwise?>
<?end choose?>
```

Check [XPath reference](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_xpath.asp)

Eventhough you are doing a `for-each` loop, `//` will navigate to the root and then just select all BATCH_SOURCE_NAME elements.

`//BATCH_SOURCE_NAME='FreightMaster'` is always true for your data because a row exists where `BATCH_SOURCE_NAME='FreightMaster'`, so `<?CT_REFERENCE?>` is printed, which is null for the first row.

In the second case `BATCH_SOURCE_NAME='MIGRATION'` is always true for the same reason, so now you print `INVOICE_NUMBER` for every row. The result is correct because `INVOICE_NUMBER` is the same as `CT_REFERENCE` for rows 2 and 3.